# Null Pointer Exception in startActivityForResult

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to invoke camera from HTML5 and JavaScript. My code is as below. But I am getting null pointer exception.

Main Activity :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
            setContentView(R.layout.main);  
            WebView webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkitWebView1); 
            WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();  
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
            //load html5 page  
            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/html/opencamera.html");  

            openCamera=new OpenCamera();  
            webview.addJavascriptInterface(openCamera,"camera");  

        }  

        @Override   
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {   
            if (requestCode== 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){   
                System.out.println("Done");  
            }  
        }
```

Camera call :

```
public class OpenCamera extends Activity {  

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    }  

    public void startCameraActivity(){  
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );  
        startActivityForResult(intent,0);  
    }  

}
```

html page :

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
    <html>  
    <head>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    function openCamera(){  
        //alert("cameras");  
        camera.startCameraActivity();  
    }  
    </script>  


    <title>Welcome</title>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
    Hello World!!!  
    <br/>  
    <button type="button" onclick="openCamera()">Capture Image</button>  
    </body>  
    </html>
```

Permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />  
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Logcat:

```
11-16 08:56:07.133: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539): java.lang.NullPointerException  
11-16 08:56:07.133: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)  
11-16 08:56:07.133: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at com.test.camera.OpenCamera.startCameraActivity(OpenCamera.java:17)  
11-16 08:56:07.133: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)  
11-16 08:56:07.133: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)  
11-16 08:56:07.133: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3300(WebViewCore.java:52)  
11-16 08:56:07.133: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1150)  
11-16 08:56:07.133: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
11-16 08:56:07.133: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)  
11-16 08:56:07.133: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:621)  
11-16 08:56:07.133: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: where do you got null pointer exception? can you please post your logcat trace?? If the null pointer occurs at first then check your webview whether you have use webview in main layout.

Comment: Can you supply the stacktrace?

Comment: Is your goal to open the camera when your activity has been started?

Comment: Are you sure,you can define onActivityResult(...) in the class other than the one where you called startActivityForResult(...) ?? I bet,you can use it like wise.

Comment: on click of button (html5), the javascript function should call the startCamera method in OpenCamera activity and the camera should capture the picture.

Comment: can you put your whole activity class here or in pastebin and give link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting `Camera Activity` from `OpenCamera` Activity which is not yet started (according to android way of starting `Activity`), So the context of `OpenCamera` Activity is null, that is why your `Context` is `null` at that time and causing `NullPointerException`.

Workaround:

Pass a context to the Function `startCameraActivity()` as

```
public void startCameraActivity(Context con){  
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );  
        con.startActivityForResult(intent,0);  
}
```

pass a context to the `WebView`

```
webview.addJavascriptInterface(this,"context");
```

and in your script

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function openCamera(){   
        camera.startCameraActivity(context);  
    }  
</script>
```

`OpenCamera` need not to be an `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

You should have the proper intent filter in the manifest file. This is the reason you are getting the exception

Comment: i did not get what you meant. could you please explain in brief.

Comment: this is what he means about intent filters. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html  should match android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Comment: i have added <activity android:name="OpenCamera"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
But of no use!!

Answer (score 0):

give this a try when you launch the camera

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.your.package.TAKE_PICTURE");  
 startActivityForResult(intent,0); 

 <activity android:name="OpenCamera" android:label="@string/app_name"> 
      <intent-filter>    
            <action android:name="com.your.package.TAKE_PICTURE" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
      </intent-filter> 
 </activity>
```